# How to set the background color of a table cell text label

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Here is some of my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
...


cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.textLabel.text = @"text";


return cell;
}
```

The text color of my label will change to blue but its background color stays as it's defined in Interface Builder!  How can I customize it?

Answer (score 1):

ok friends, finally found it.  the answer is to override willDisplayCell, which for some reason, is the last place where the background color is set

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to make sure the opacity is set correctly, maybe its see through rather than a color?

Comment: No. It shows the labels's background that's defined in the IB, not the background of the cell's content view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

**Edit :** check below SO post, could be helpful for you.

[UILabel Setting Transparent Background Color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753231/uilabel-setting-transparent-background-color)